# Declaring global variables in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, properties, global-variables

I have a question about variable declaration in Objective-C

in case of `global variable` what is the difference between declaration in the `.m` file and `.h` file?

should i declare `property` for each variable in `.h` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring global variables in .h and in .m has the same effect just like declaring global variable in .h and in .c. However, it is a good practice to declare it in your .h.

Comment: Apple has built in support of class extensions in xcode. Its better practice to declare in class extension (which you dont want to use outside) rather than in .h.....refer apple reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you put it in the .h file, then things that include the .h file can access it directly. If you want that, do that. Otherwise put it in the .m.